# Not Producing Expected Results for If/Else Statement + Concatenation

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 different tables (worksheets) that I'm using, all in the same workbook.  The first worksheet is called "Conv Event" and it contains the Conversion Event and Date. The data in "Conv Event" looks like this:

[image: Conv Event Table]

The second worksheet is called "Eco Event" and it contains the Name and Conversion Event.  The data in "Eco Event" looks like this:

[image: Eco Event Table]

The third worksheet is called "APM MASTER" and it contains the Name and EC Events. The Name is in Column G and EC Events is in Column H of this worksheet.

What I'm trying to accomplish with the code below is to 
1) Look up the Names in the "Eco Event" table which match/have the same Name as the Name in the "APM Master" table
2) Take the Conversion Events from those matches (i.e. where you have the same Name in the "APM Master" table and "Eco Event" table) in the "Eco Event" table and match the events to the same events in the "Conv Event" table 
3) Concatenate the Conversion Events and Date from the "Conv Event" table into Column H of the "APM Master" table where the Name in Column G in "APM Master" table matches the Name in Column A from the "Eco Event" table.

APM Master table should look like the below:

[image: APM Master Table Results]

The code runs error-free, however, when I run it, nothing shows up in Column H of the "APM Master" worksheet.  Can someone help me figure out why the code isn't producing the expected results, just blank cells?

```
Sub EarlyConversion()

With Worksheets("APM MASTER")

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Eco Event").Range("A2:A387")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Eco Event").Range("B2:B387")
Set ws = Worksheets("Conv Event")
LastRow = .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A6")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A7")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A8")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A9")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A10")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A11")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A12")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A13")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A14")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A15")) > 0 Then

      .Range("H" & i) = ws.Range("A6").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B6") & ", " & ws.Range("A7").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B7") & ", " & ws.Range("A8").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B8") & ", " & ws.Range("A9").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B9") & ", " & ws.Range("A10").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B10") & ", " & ws.Range("A11").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B11") & ", " & ws.Range("A12").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B12") & ", " & ws.Range("A13").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B13") & ", " & ws.Range("A14").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B14") & ", " & ws.Range("A15").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B15")

    ElseIf Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A6")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A7")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A8")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A9")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A10")) > 0 And
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A11")) > 0 And   
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A12")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A13")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A14")) > 0 Then

      .Range("H" & i) = ws.Range("A6").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B6") & ", " & ws.Range("A7").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B7") & ", " & ws.Range("A8").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B8") & ", " & ws.Range("A9").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B9") & ", " & ws.Range("A10").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B10") & ", " & ws.Range("A11").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B11") & ", " & ws.Range("A12").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B12") & ", " & ws.Range("A13").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B13") & ", " & ws.Range("A14").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B14")

    ElseIf Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A6")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A7")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A8")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A9")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A10")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A11")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A12")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A13")) > 0 Then

      .Range("H" & i) = ws.Range("A6").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B6") & ", " & ws.Range("A7").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B7") & ", " & ws.Range("A8").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B8") & ", " & ws.Range("A9").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B9") & ", " & ws.Range("A10").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B10") & ", " & ws.Range("A11").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B11") & ", " & ws.Range("A12").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B12") & ", " & ws.Range("A13").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B13")

    ElseIf Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A6")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A7")) > 0 And 
    Application.CountIfs(rng1, 
    Worksheets("APM MASTER").Range("G" & i), rng2, 
    ws.Range("A8")) > 0 Then

      .Range("H" & i) = ws.Range("A6").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B6") & ", " & ws.Range("A7").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B7") & ", " & ws.Range("A8").Value & ": " & 
        ws.Range("B8")
... 

End If
Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tim Williams, thank you for getting my pictures to show up in my post!  I couldn't get them to post properly.

Comment: @Tim Williams, I corrected the CountIfs function in my code, as you mentioned on the previous question I posted.  And I also tried the code you wrote with the loop through A6:A15, but I'm still getting blank calls in Column H of "APM Master" worksheet.  I appreciate the help though!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub EarlyConversion()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rngConvEvt As Range, rw As Range, dt
    Dim rngEcoEvt As Range, ecNum As String, s As String

    Set rngConvEvt = Worksheets("Conv Event").Range("A2:A400") 'adjust to suit
    Set rngEcoEvt = Worksheets("Eco Event").Range("A2:B400")   'adjust to suit

    With Worksheets("APM MASTER")
        LastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'not h?
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            s = ""
            For Each rw In rngEcoEvt.Rows
                'matching name?
                If rw.Cells(1).Value = .Cells(i, "G").Value Then
                    ecNum = rw.Cells(2).Value 'matches: get the EC number
                    dt = Application.VLookup(ecNum, rngConvEvt, 2, False)
                    If Not IsError(dt) Then
                        'got a match on ECNum: add to string
                        s = s & IIf(s <> "", ",", "") & ecNum & ":" & dt
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "No match on " & ecNum
                    End If
                End If
            Next rw
            .Cells(i, "H").Value = s
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### An Unusual Data Transformation

- What's unusual about it is that it is dependent on the headers and the sheet names rather than on the rows and columns as usually. So before you use it check all the first 9 constants carefully. They must be the same as in your workbook, or the program will fail. Of course, non of these words (used for headers) can be used alone in a cell before (rows above and the same row before) the actual headers.
- Change the 10th and 11th constants for the separators as you prefer.
- All 4 procedures have to be copied to a standard `module` (e.g.`Module1`). You run the first procedure which is a `sub` that calls (uses) the other 3 `functions`.
- I wrote the code in this way because you asked your question with such a rare precision, that I couldn't resist. I hope you'll find it useful.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    ' Constants
    Const SheetCE As String = "Conv Event"
    Const SheetEE As String = "Eco Event"
    Const SheetAM As String = "APM Master"
    Const hCE1 As String = "Conversion Event"
    Const hCE2 As String = "Date"
    Const hEE1 As String = "Name"
    Const hEE2 As String = "Conversion Event"
    Const NameHeader As String = "Name"
    Const EventsHeader As String = "EC Events"
    Const NameSeparator As String = ": "
    Const EventSeparator As String = ", "
    'Other Variables
    Dim wsCE As Worksheet, wsEE As Worksheet, wsAM As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim CE_Event, CE_Date, EE_Name, EE_Event, AM_Name, AM_Events
    Dim CurrName As String, CurrEvent As String, CurrResult As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ' Define worksheets.
    Set wsCE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetCE)
    Set wsEE = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetEE)
    Set wsAM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetAM)
    ' Write Source Columns to Source Arrays.
    CE_Event = getColumnBelowHeader(wsCE, hCE1)
    CE_Date = getColumnBelowHeader(wsCE, hCE2)
    EE_Name = getColumnBelowHeader(wsEE, hEE1)
    EE_Event = getColumnBelowHeader(wsEE, hEE2)
    ' Write from Source Arrays to Target Array.
    AM_Name = getUniqueColumn(EE_Name)
    ReDim AM_Events(1 To UBound(AM_Name), 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(AM_Name)
        CurrName = AM_Name(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(EE_Name)
            If EE_Name(j, 1) = CurrName Then
                CurrEvent = EE_Event(j, 1)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(CurrEvent, CE_Event, 0)) Then
                    GoSub writeAM_Events
                Else
                    MsgBox CurrEvent & " not found."
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Write to Target Worksheet.
    Set rng = getHeaderCell(wsAM, NameHeader)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
      rng.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(AM_Name)) = AM_Name
    Set rng = getHeaderCell(wsAM, EventsHeader)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
      rng.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(AM_Events)) = AM_Events
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Operation finshed successfully.", vbInformation
    ' Debug.print
    For i = 1 To UBound(AM_Name)
        Debug.Print AM_Name(i, 1), AM_Events(i, 1)
    Next i

GoTo exitProcedure

writeAM_Events:
    k = Application.Match(CurrEvent, CE_Event, 0)
    CurrResult = CE_Event(k, 1) & NameSeparator & CE_Date(k, 1)
    If AM_Events(i, 1) <> "" Then _
      CurrResult = AM_Events(i, 1) & EventSeparator & CurrResult
    AM_Events(i, 1) = CurrResult
Return

exitProcedure:

End Sub

' Writes the values of the non-empty column range below the first found
' specified string to a 2D one-based one-column array.
Function getColumnBelowHeader(Sheet As Worksheet, Header As String) As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range
    Set rng = getHeaderCell(Sheet, Header)
    With Sheet
        Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:=Header, _
          After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
        If rng.Row = .Rows.Count Then GoTo exitError
        Set FirstCell = rng.Offset(1)
        Set rng = .Range(FirstCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, FirstCell.Column))
        Set LastCell = rng.Find(What:="*", _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If LastCell Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
        getColumnBelowHeader = .Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
    End With
GoTo exitProcedure
exitError:
    getColumnBelowHeader = Array()
exitProcedure:
End Function

' Returns the first cell range where a specified string was found.
Function getHeaderCell(Sheet As Worksheet, Header As String) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    With Sheet
        Set getHeaderCell = Sheet.Cells.Find(What:=Header, _
          After:=Sheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    End With
End Function

' Creates a 2D one-based one-column array with unique values of another
' 2D one-base one-column array (usually data from column in worksheet).
Function getUniqueColumn(ColumnArray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim dict As Object, Key As Variant, TargetArray As Variant, i As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(ColumnArray)
        If Not IsMissing(ColumnArray(i, 1)) Then
            dict(ColumnArray(i, 1)) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim TargetArray(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 1): i = 1
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        TargetArray(i, 1) = Key
        i = i + 1
    Next Key
    getUniqueColumn = TargetArray
End Function
```